# pusher.subcribe() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pusher

```
 pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_evenHt', {"message": "hello world"});

   var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
  channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
   alert('An event was triggered with message: ' + data.message);
  });

  pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', {"message": "hello world"});
```

I've initialized pusher at the top of the file. Here is the internals of a method thats throwing the error. The `pusher.trigger()` function works correctly, but the next line throws an error on `pusher.subcribe();`

> TypeError: pusher.subscribe is not a function

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 8):

I assume you're using pusher-http-node? Pusher-http-node does not have the subscribe function, as it is a server http library.

If you wish to use our JS websocket library on the server, you can `npm install pusher-js`, and import `pusher-js/node`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the API key for channel subscribe the channel.

https://github.com/dirkbonhomme/pusher-client-node#global-events